# Comment out line, only if previous line contains matching string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Looking for a solution for a `bash` script using `sed` or `awk` to comment out a line, only if the previous line contains a matching string.

For example, a file containing:

```
...

if [ $V1 -gt 100 ]; then
some specific commands
else
some other specific commands
fi

...
```

I'd like to comment out the line containing `else` but ONLY if the previous line contains `specific`.

I've attempted piping multiple `sed` commands along with `grep` commands to no avail.

Comment: You mean comment the whole else part?

Comment: no, actually, simply that line.

Comment: wrt `I've attempted piping multiple sed commands along with grep commands to no avail.`. If you think you need sed+grep, you don't, you either just need sed or just need grep or you need awk. I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -E '/specific/{n;s/^([[:blank:]]*)else$/\1#else/}'
```

**Output**

```
...

if [ $V1 -gt 100 ]; then
some specific commands
#else
some other commands
fi

...
```

**A retrospection**

1. `/specific/` look for the line containing the pattern *specific*
2. `n` add the next line to the pattern space. `n` auto prints the current pattern space.
3. Check if the next line is `(one_or_more_spaces)else`,if yes, substitute the line with a `(one_or_more_spaces_found_previously)#else`. Remember `()` is for pattern reuse and `\1` is the previously matched pattern reused.
4. `-E` enable extended regex
5. `-i` is for inplace edit of the actual file

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason that's also commenting out the following line. In my case, `specific` shows up in multiple places. I think I need to match `else` and go from there?

Comment: This will actually comment every line next to `specific` line.

Comment: Yeah, I see/understand that. Unfortunately, not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @TryTryAgain : Is the edited script not working for you?

Comment: or simply `sed '/specific/{n;s/^else$/#else/}'`

Comment: You may consider: `sed '/specific/{n;s/^[[:blank:]]*else/#&/}' file`

Comment: @hek2mgl : Thankyou and adopted.

Comment: @sjsam it sure is, great! Thanks, everyone, great comments too.

Comment: @anubhava &   \@hek2mgl : Thanks folks. Adopted both the suggestions.

Comment: @sjsam may need to open another question, but any reason you'd see why replacing #2 `n` with `p` doesn't work for previous line?

Comment: @TryTryAgain : Well, `p` just print the line. `n` prints the current line and moves the next line to the pattern space. If you just print the line, the line is still the line with `specific command` and searching `else` in this line gives a negative result and nothing happens

Comment: @TryTryAgain Objective is 1. find the /pattern/ 2. move to the **n**ext line 3.check if line is else and if so change it.

Comment: @anubhava : Comment#7 is pragmatic considering the indentation that people put in the script these days.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk solution:

```
awk '/specific/{p=NR} NR==p+1{p=0; if (/^[[:blank:]]*else/) $0 = "#" $0} 1' file

if [ $V1 -gt 100 ]; then
some specific commands
#else
some other commands
fi
```

- In this block `/specific/p=NR` we find `specific` and store current line # in `p`
- Next block is executed for very next line due to `p == NR+1` condition
- We rest `p=0` and if that line has `else` at start with optional whitespaces before we just comment it out.

Comment: And `awk` does it very well. This works and appears pretty robust/reusable for my case. Thanks for the answer, can you please expand/explain the logic in your `awk` answer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I just added some explanation in my answer, let me know if you have any specific question.