# Comment out line, only if following line contains matching string

Tags: awk, sed

The opposite of this question [Comment out line, only if previous line contains matching string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209172/comment-out-line-only-if-previous-line-contains-matching-string) ... I'd like to use `sed` or `awk` to comment out the line containing `if` but ONLY if the following line contains `specific`.

In this example:

```
...

if [ $V1 -gt 100 ]; then
some specific commands
else
some other specific commands
fi

...
```

I'd want the line starting with `if` commented out because the following line contains `specific`.

Comment: what happens to the `else` block?  Trying to preempt the follow up question...

Comment: @karakfa using the previous question, I've already sloppily commented them out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209172/comment-out-line-only-if-previous-line-contains-matching-string

Comment: @hek2mgl I've tried a bunch of nonsense not worth including (changing `n` to `p` for the `sed` answer, changing `p+1` to `p-1` in the `awk` answer and many things like that). In trying to turn the answers to my previous question into the opposite (following line instead of previous) for a solution to this question.

Comment: I don't see any attempts here. Nothing to help than giving you the final solution. You'll learn nothing (like before)

Comment: OK, what happens to `fi` then?  Do you want to remove the if condition and run both statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed :

```
sed '/^if/{N;/specific/{s/^/#/}}' file
```

Add the `-i` option to edit the file *in place* :

```
sed -i '/^if/{N;/specific/{s/^/#/}}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. It works a bit better by forgiving the possibility of whitespace like this too: `sed '/^[[:blank:]]*if/{N;/umask/{s/^/#/}}'`

Comment: You are going WAY off the rails using sed for this or anything else involving changes that span multiple input lines. The sed constructs for this became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and any sed solution you get will be fragile, non-portable, inefficient, and hard to enhance as your requirements evolve.

Comment: @EdMorton IMO the right tool is the one that meets a need and a knowledge. Awk may be a better choice in some cases, but you can promote it without depreciating sed, by simply writing you awk solution, OP will be judge. And please note that although it's obsolete, [GNU Sed 4.3](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/sed-devel/) is in progress.

Comment: Given 2 scripts that produce the output they want from some sample input they provided, the OP is usually unable to tell the difference between a robust, portable, efficient script and one that's not so it's up to those of us with more experience to help them understand that difference. sed is a great tool, I use it almost daily (and have posted many answers in SO using sed), but it's just not the right tool for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do what you may be asking for in this question:

```
$ cat preCmt.awk
{
    print ((pre ~ /^[[:space:]]*if/) && /specific/ ? "#" : "") pre
    pre = $0
}
END { print pre }

$ awk -f preCmt.awk file

...

#if [ $V1 -gt 100 ]; then
some specific commands
else
some other specific commands
fi

...
```

and here's what you may be asking to do in your previous question:

```
$ cat postCmt.awk
{
    print (/^[[:space:]]*else/ && (pre ~ /specific/) ? "#" : "") $0
    pre = $0
}

$ awk -f postCmt.awk file
...

if [ $V1 -gt 100 ]; then
some specific commands
#else
some other specific commands
fi

...
```

The above will work efficiently and robustly in all awks in all OSes and will be easy to enhance if/when your requirements changes.

Comment: Good answer! I would still admit that I would personally go with the `sed` solution here. I mean the task as described in the question is definitely not something for a stable, portable, production solution. For a quick hack on the command line `sed` looks fine for me in this case.

Comment: Thanks. IMHO if all that was needed was a quick command on the command line the OP would be better off just editing the file and make the change manually. Also doing simple things like this in awk is a good way to get familiar with the right approach so it's easy to do more complicated things later. You can't/shouldn't expand these sed commands to do anything else so learning how to do this in sed is pointless. And remember others looking for solutions to similar problems will see this and they may not be using GNU sed and/or have other requirements.